# Rays bouncing inside a semicircle

Tags: geometry

Think of a semicircle with a diameter AB. Now consider a light beam going off of point A and travelling towards the arc of the semicircle.

The ray *does not* bounce off straight lines tangent to the arc of the semi-circle.

Instead, the ray bounces off the arc of the semi-circle *as if the arc was instead a straight line parallel to the diameter*. The ray goes towards the diameter, and then bounces from the diameter back towards the arc.

If the light beam exits point A with an angle theta, hits the arc four times and ends up perfectly at point B, what angle would theta be?

Be aware that the sketch is not to scale! Because of symmetry, the second bounce off of the diameter would be in the center of the semicircle and all colored angles would be the same.

[image]

Comment: ... The trajectory you have represented follows what is indicated in the question but the question is devoid of physical meaning.

Comment: ... because a ray hitting the semicircle will not be reflected like that at all...

Comment: It's better to post your attempt and where you are stuck

Comment: With the unphysical bouncing you specify, the center bounce on the diameter should be at the center of the circle.  The four bounces on the arc should be two symmetric pairs.  All the angles on the diameter should be the same and if you draw a horizontal line where the ray hits the arc the angles should be the same as on the diameter.

Comment: Yes I know, I forgot to mention that the sketch is not at all to scale...

Comment: Considering [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/yKYmppw.png) and knowing the triangles are similar it's not so hard to deduce the equation on $x$, where $X(x,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for the interior angle $\angle CAE$ of an isosceles triangle $ACE$ with $AC = CE$ whose base $AE$ is on diameter $AB$ and opposite vertex $C$ on semicircle $AB$, such that another similar triangle $\triangle EDO \sim \triangle ACE$ with $D$ on semicircle $AB$ has $O$ at the midpoint of $AB$.

As such, let $\theta = \angle CAE$ and let $x = AE$.  Assume without loss of generality that $AO = 1$, thus $EO = 1-x$.  But $\triangle AOC \cong \triangle EDO$ because $\angle CAO = \angle CAE = \theta$ and $AO = CO = 1$, hence $\angle ACO = \angle CAO = \theta$.  It follows that $AC = 1-x$.  But by similarity, $$\frac{AC}{AE} = \frac{DE}{EO},$$ or $$\frac{1-x}{x} = \frac{1}{1-x},$$ hence $$x = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ and $$\theta = \cos^{-1} \frac{1-x}{2} = \cos^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} \approx 1.2566370614359172954$$ radians.

Comment: [$=\frac{2\pi}{5}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%28%28sqrt%285%29-1%29%2F4%29%2Fpi)